# Using Field Calculator in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser

I am using Esri ArcMap 10.3:

I have a very large table so I do no want to do this manually it will take me months (50k+ rows of data)

My table looks something like below example.

**Purpose**           **new field**
multi family
apple
jack
random
random

Of course my real table is way bigger and the 'purpose' field has many more unqiue values.

So what I would like to do is use the field calculator on my "new field"
and have it add a value of 'xx' for each row that had a purpose value of 'apple' and jack'.

So basically if purpose was 'jack' or 'random' then new field will be 'xx'

This could be done with python im sure but I was just going to use the calculate field tool and write in an expression.

Comment: For coding questions, please include your best code attempt in the question.  This is a requirement for this forum for coding questions.

Comment: By code, in this instance, we would expect to see what you are typing into the Code Block and Expression with the Python Parser of the ArcGIS Field Calculator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Granted this is without Python and a smaller dataset, but what I have done in the past is:

- Add the new field
- Open the attribute table
- Perform a Select by Attributes query for your target
- Click the [View Selected Records](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/viewing-all-or-only-the-selected-records.htm) option
- Use the field calculator to populate your new field with your values

Comment: you can option to skip the 4th bullet (view selected records) because the result will still be the same. Be sure the field calculator specifies to calculate only selected records (which it does by default).

Answer (score 5):

Open the Attribute Table and right click on the table you want to edit and select Field Calculator and select python and show codeblock

```
def calc(table):
     if table == "apple":
         return "XX"
     elif table == "pear":
         return "YY"
     else:
         return "ZZ"
```

Then in the bottom

```
table2 (the one you right clicked on) = calc(!table!)
```

table = the table that holds the values of "apple" , "pear" , "jack" etc...
table2 is the table you are doing the field calculate on

with your values it should be:

```
def calc(PROPUSE): 
     if PROPUSE == "CONDOMINIUM":
          return "MFR" 
     elif PROPUSE == "COOPERATIVE": 
          return "MFR" 

Existing = calc(!PROPUSE!)
```

Comment: Awseom this is what I was thinking, creating a function to do this my python isnt the best and your code gave me errors.  "000539 : Error message from Python." This error code covers a number of Python errors:

Example error 1: exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects. 
The above is a Python-specific error. The calculation is attempting to add or concatenate a string and a number. 

Example error 2: Invalid field shape@distance 
The above is an error using the geometry object. The distance method is not a valid method of the geometry object.

Comment: Can you paste in a copy of what your DB looks like,  usually that is a type error (trying to concatenate a string and an int, or trying to put a string in an int type field) , I just pasted that code into field calc and it worked on my end.  What is the exact code you are using?

Comment: def calc(PROPUSE):
     if PROPUSE == "CONDOMINIUM":
         return "MFR"
     elif PROPUSE == "COOPERATIVE":
         return "MFR"
     else:
         return True

Existing = calc(!PROPUSE!)

Comment: Not sure how to post code into the correct format in the 'comments' window

Comment: Why the else: return True?  just leave that off.

Comment: Not sure your og code had else return 'zz' and I did not want other values being created in the new field. Ok I will just remove the else but i thought if/else conditions would have to end with the else statement?

Comment: see update in my answer, and you could always end with else: return "" for a blank or else isNull i believe for a null value (not completely sure on that last one, I would have to look it up, someone can probably correct me)

Comment: Those if statements need to be bracketed, e.g. `if (PROPUSE == CONDOMINIUM):`

Comment: Awesome! I read in the help docs that field names had to be labeled such as " !field_name!" Either way i will check this out on monday when i get back to work. They kick us out at 5:15pm on fridays so IT can run updates before the weekend. Thanks for the help ill post back Monday!